# Hide if array is more than 1 in angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-directives

I am very much upset trying with unsuccessful result.

There is an object array where inside the object there is/are a booking id/ids. Booking Id is an array inside the object. Booking Id hold 1 or more no. of booking id. I want to hide the booking id if there is only 1 booking id else I would like to display them.

How ever my code display all even if it is 1 or more.

```
    getBookingIds(){
  var myResult = this.customers;
    for(var i=0; i<myResult.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<myResult[i].bookingIds.length; j++){
        if(myResult[i].bookingIds.length > 2) {
          this.bookingId = true
        } else {
          this.bookingId = false;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
            <span class="bkidwrap" >
            <span class="bkids" *ngFor="let myBookingId of customer.bookingIds">
                <span class="bkid" *ngIf="bookingId">{{myBookingId}}</span>
            </span>
        </span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using hidden property binding by comparing the lengthas below

```
<span class="bkidwrap" >
      <span class="bkids" *ngFor="let myBookingId of customer.bookingIds" 
                  [hidden]="customer.bookingIds.length === 1">
           <span class="bkid" >{{myBookingId}}</span>
      </span>
 </span>
```

Comment: I am continuously looking at your code. It seems very helpful. Waiting to see the result.

Comment: Its finally working brother. Thank you. I just want to cry in peace.